# how to convert two dimension array to one dimension in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array looks like this (two dimensions):

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]]
```

How can I change it to: `[1 1 1 1 ............1 0 1]`
I've been looking for solution for a whole afternoon but still got no idea, can someone give me some hint, thanks.

Comment: `arr.ravel()` or `arr.flatten()`?

Comment: Did you spend any of that afternoon reading the basic numpy documentation?  Like the quick start tutorial?

Comment: @High-Octane, he does call it an array, and use a `[numpy]` tag.  And the display(s) is normal for `numpy` arrays, not lists.  In `numpy` `reshape` (and `ravel`) produces a `view` (usually), which is fast and memory efficient.  Your flattener may be nice for lists, but will be slower when applied to a numpy array (if it works at all :) ).

Comment: I didn't notice the numpy tag and aren't numpy arrays output tags like this ? array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9]). In any case I'm at mistake here and I'll remove my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a numpy array `a`:

```
np.squeeze(a)
```

or

```
a.flatten()
```